# SQL issue with Having

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve this problem.

Return a table that lists language and number of speakers, but only include languages that have > 200,000,000 speakers? Order these results high to low based on the number of speakers

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    Language,
    Percentage / 100 AS 'Percentage',
    SUM(Population) AS Population,
    Population * Percentage AS 'Speakers'
FROM 
    language
GROUP BY 
    Language
HAVING 
    Speakers > 200000000;
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using the calculated expression of speakers in having

```
SELECT 
     Language,
     Percentage/100 AS 'Percentage',
     SUM(Population) AS Population,
     SUM(Population)*(Percentage/100) AS 'Speakers'
FROM language
GROUP BY Language
HAVING SUM(Population)*(Percentage/100)> 200000000
ORDER BY SUM(Population)*(Percentage/100) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  That is a really bad habit.  Using single quotes only for string and date constants.

SQL (in general) allows you to refer to column aliases in the `ORDER BY`.  Some databases allow you to reference them in the `HAVING` clause as well -- but not all.

I'm not sure what `Percentage` is supposed to do.  It should be in the `GROUP BY`.  In other cases, `Percentage` should be part of the aggregation calculation:

```
SELECT Language,
       SUM(Percentage * Population / 100) / SUM(Population) AS Percentage,
       SUM(Population) AS Population,
       SUM(Population * Percentage/100) AS Speakers
FROM language
GROUP BY Language
HAVING SUM(Population*Percentage/100.0) > 200000000
ORDER BY Speakers DESC;
```

Note that some databases do integer division, so 99/100 = 0, not 0.99.  For this reason, I would do:

```
SELECT Language, 
       SUM(Percentage * Population / 100.0) / SUM(Population) AS Percentage,
       SUM(Population) AS Population,
       SUM(Population*Percentage/100.0) AS Speakers
FROM language
GROUP BY Language
HAVING SUM(Population*Percentage/100.0) > 200000000
ORDER BY Speakers DESC;
```